# Symfony v2.4 simple_form > login_form results in ServiceNotFoundException

Tags: php, security, symfony

I receive the following exception if I use the "simple_form"-option in my security.yml:

```
ServiceNotFoundException: The service "security.firewall.map.context.secured_area"
has a dependency on a non-existent service
"security.authentication.success_handler.secured_area.simple_form".
```

And I need the "simple_form" sinds it has the "authenticator"-option.
Using "form_login" results in the following exception:

```
InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "authenticator" under "security.firewalls.secured_area.form_login"
```

My security.yml (only relevant config copied)

```
security:
  firewalls:
    secured_area:
      simple_form:
        login_path: /login
        check_path: /login_check
        authenticator: some_wild_authenticator
        use_referer: true
        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        success_handler: security.authentication.success_handler
        failure_handler: security.authentication.failure_handler
```

Did I miss something? Bug? Not possible? Solution? Workaround?

I run SF2.4

[Source](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html)

Comment: `pattern: ^/your_pattern` is missing

Comment: No I have it, not copied it since it's inrelevant.

Comment: Please look at my security config, http://pastebin.com/ZJgC0LZw  its worked for me

Comment: You don't have my option **"authenticator"**.

Comment: @Airoude did you figure this out?  I am running into the exact same problem.

Comment: @msumme I removed the "authenticator"-option and used the **form_login** instead and putted the logic in my **success_handler**/**failure_handler**

Comment: @airoude Thanks - I solved it by overriding the service definition that it complained about not having instead of setting my own success_handler.  Hacky - but otherwise would have had to write a much more complicated authentication provider...

Answer (score 1):

there's a bug in Symfony and you have to register `success_handler` as service id `security.authentication.success_handler.secured_area.simple_form`, using other names for of service will result with the exception

```
ServiceNotFoundException: The service "security.firewall.map.context.secured_area" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.authentication.success_handler.secured_area.simple_form".
```

this [error](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10147) still occurs in Symfony 2.5.8

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your services.yml:

```
parameters:
    custom.success.handler.class: Acme\DemoBundle\Security\CustomLoginSuccessHandler

services:
    security.authentication.success_handler.secured_area.simple_form:
        class: %custom.success.handler.class%
        tags:
          - { name: 'monolog.logger', channel: 'security' }
```

Replace the "custom success handler" stuff with the information relevant to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered (and this is not a "best practice") a workaround.

I redefined my success_handler service as "security.authentication.success_handler.secured_area.simple_form" (or in my case - a different string than "secured_area").

By giving it that name, and not using the "success_handler" option under simple_form, I was able to get my success handler to be used.

I'm hoping they fix this soon, as that kind of workaround makes me a little uneasy during updates.

Answer (score -1):

Use FOS User bundle  [FOS User Bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)  for this. Please see the documentation and configure this security firewall properly.

Comment: This bundle would be one of the last I'd recommend.

Comment: @Anyone And why is that?

Comment: (1) Because FOS Bundles contain 90% of code that is not needed, should be separated. (2) That bundles is only good as long as you use it exactly the way it's designed without custom changes.